Tailwind classes are not working after installing tailwind via npm
I installed tailwind css with npm, and then I build the css to get the output.css file but when testing it the classes are not working.
Here are the scripts I use :
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "devserver": "live-server public",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel build:css devserver"
  }

Directory file path :
(https://i.sstatic.net/JpmsHz52.png)
in src/input.css,
@import "tailwindcss/base";

@import "tailwindcss/components";

@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

in tailwind.config.js;
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./public/*.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

in public/index.html,
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/output.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="bg-sky-500 hover:bg-sky-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Save changes</button>
</body>
</html>

The browser result
(https://i.sstatic.net/jt3LSdnF.png)

It seems like your CSS file is not loading into the webpage. This is because the web root is public, so one cannot request a file outside of this via ../. Instead, you could try compiling the output CSS from Tailwind into the same public folder like:
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./public/output.css --watch

Then, you can link to this CSS file in index.html:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./output.css">

